# Excel sheet - suggestion for report creation

Tags: vba, powershell, pivot-table, powerquery, excel-2016

I need to create report using excel sheet 2016.

As shown in diagram, each 'Service Name' column has multiple services names, same service may keep repeating. Each 'Service Name' column get an unique 'Transaction id' till it completes it. Later if same 'Service Name' can repeat , will get new 'Transaction id'.

My requirement is to find the 'Time stamp' which has min and max value associated with corresponding  'Service Name' and 'Transaction id' value . Once these values are found, should be populated as new table in new sheet of the same excel. Any suggestion on this please?

[image]

Comment: MINIFS and MAXIFS might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Create a pivot table with your data. Change the pivot layout to tabular and do not show any subtotals or grandtotals. The row will be the service_name and trans_id. Then drag the timestamp to the Values section twice. Right-Click on any pivot timecell you want to reflect as the minimum and select Summarize Values by... MIN. Do the same with the other timecell column, but select MAX.

Results are...

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick response. I have tried the above steps, but it shows timestamp as 'zero' value in Min and Max column. Later I have tried apply custom number format as 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000' , but later it had showed same value for all min and max as '1900-01-00 00:00:00.000' .  Please suggest .

Comment: This time, I have remove data from the column and retained just time in column. Now it showed min and max time . Any suggestion how to do the same with date-timestamp ?

Comment: My screenshot reflected the format of yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000 in the data (column C) before making the pivot. Is your data also formatted that way before pivoting? Not sure why yours is not performing the same. That's odd, sorry.

Comment: Hi, I have imported data from database using excel 'From Microsoft Query' and then applied step which you had mentioned including applying format as 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000' . Am not sure what is causing the issue, am excel 2016 version. Can this be done using Power Query?